# Function runs manually but not with onOpen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to run the following script in Apps script from a trigger and it doesn't work, but it works fine when I call it manually from the IDE. When I look at execution history I see it failed but there is no error log.

Any ideas?

```
function customOnOpen() {
  Logger.log('Script name: customOnOpen');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Functions')
      .addItem('Make Sheet Static', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.makeStatic')
      .addItem('Make Sheet Dynamic', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.makeDynamic')
      .addItem('Count Cells', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.countCells')
      .addItem('Find Functions in Spreadhseet', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.checkSheetForFormulas')
      .addItem('Fnd Dependent Cells', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.traceDependents')
      .addItem('Trim Sheet', 'HelperFunctionsLibrary.trimSheet')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Your script works perfectly whether run manually or using on onOpen trigger, both simple and installable. I guess you're applying it to a spreadsheet that you have no access to create and anchor triggers on.

Comment: Please add more details like the steps that you followed to create the installable trigger, if you are the spreadsheet owner or if it's shared with you.

Answer (score 1):

In fact Ruben pointed me to the answer. The library was owned by one gmail account and the spreadsheet referencing the library was in another. I just shared the library with the other gmail account and everything worked fine. Probably the issue was that I was referencing the head version of the library instead of a deployment, so sharing the script solved that issue.